# Self-hosted Next.js app with Clerk Dev Auth, session not recognized in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, next.js, clerk

I am not sure what's the next step for debugging and haven't been able to resolve my issue on Clerk's Discord or GH Issues, feels like maybe it's not a clerk issue but a Next.js issue?

I have a self-hosted next.js app in a docker container on an EC2 instance. The infra is:

```
CloudFlare -> Caddy reverse proxy (in docker) -> next.js app (in docker)
```

I've set up clerkdev and things are working well in localhost, but on production, the user session/auth data is not passed to the backend.

I've set `debug: true`

In my `afterAuth` middleware, I see that my keys are configured properly and that there is a `cookieToken`. In the `headers`, I see there's a `__session` entry that's the same as the `cookieToken`.

When the request comes in after my users signs in via Clerk, the `auth` param is empty:

```
auth {
  sessionClaims: null,
  sessionId: null,
  session: null,
  userId: null,
  user: null,
  actor: null,
  orgId: null,
  orgRole: null,
  orgSlug: null,
  organization: null,
  getToken: [Function: getToken],
  debug: [Function],
  isPublicRoute: true,
  isApiRoute: false
}
```

What new things can I try to debug this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue - just asked in their discord. Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This issue consistently affected certain users for me, and my solution was to "manually" verify and read the userId from the `__session` cookie from the `req` object using the `jose` library:

```
import Cookies from "cookies";
const { jwtVerify, createLocalJWKSet } = require('jose');

const JWKS = createLocalJWKSet({
  "keys": [ yourClerkJWTPublicKey ],
})

const cookies = new Cookies(req);
const token = req.cookies["_parsed"].get("__session").value;
const jwt = jwtVerify(token, JWKS, {clockTolerance: "7 days"});
const userId = jwt.sub;
```

You can also use `jsonwebtoken` instead of `jose` since you're running on an EC2 instance. It's a little more user friendly, though it won't work in Vercel where the `crypto` module isn't available